# Кроссбраузерная кастомизация системного скроллбара

Tags: прокрутка, кроссбраузерность, scrollbar

Добрый день! Решил перейти к использованию [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), но немного ознакомившись с ним и прочитав отзывы, пришел к такому выводу, что не на всех мобильных устройствах этот плагин будет поддерживаться. Или я ошибаюсь? Разной информации и советов на просторах интернета море. И все же, хотелось бы еще раз услышать мнения более опытных специалистов на STACK OVERFLOW. Стоит ли этот плагин использовать или все же порекомендуете что-то другое? Цель как и у всех одна - нужна поддержка во всех современных и "не совсем современных" браузерах (но за исключением совсем старых), в том числе на всех мобильных устройствах. Благодарю за полезные советы и рекомендации!

Comment: Я что-то сходу не припомню в браузерах Андроида никаких системных скроллбаров. В других приложениях видел, но не в браузере. Везде прокрутка перетаскиванием.

Comment: И отдельного блока тоже. Его причем из-за отсутствия скроллбара не всегда можно распознать и это немного бесит...

Comment: Не стоит, потому что поддержка плагина прекратилась, а багов у него много. я замучился с ним в своё время. На момент написания этого комментария у репозитория плагина [**342 открытых issues**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues) и [**23 pull requests**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/pulls). // Единственный найденный мною плагин, заменяющий нативный body скроллбар браузеров и поддерживаемый на март 2018 разработчиком — [**gemini scrollbar**](https://noeldelgado.github.io/gemini-scrollbar/). Спасибо.

Comment: LADYX, нашёл сейчас, какие лично у меня проблемы были с Malihu scrollbar, из-за чего перешёл к использованию другого плагина. // **1.** Не получилось связать его с [**JQuery Lazy**](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) для lazy loading. // **2.** Переходы по якорям работают некорректно. // **3.** Не работает с браузерным поиском через [**Ctrl+F**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/486#issuecomment-298243647). // Разработчик неактивен, исправлять будет уже вряд ли. Спасибо.

Comment: LADYX, и общего характера совет: если проект заброшен, всегда ищите альтернативы ему. Баги попадаются везде, но в заброшенных проектах никто их не исправит. Спасибо.

Comment: LADYX, у меня записано, что забраковал его, но не помню, за что именно. Возможно, потому что поскольку [**разработчик тоже не отвечает на issues**](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues), и шанс, что баги будут исправлены, невелики. Спасибо.

Comment: LADYX, [**пример страницы с Gemini Scrollbar**](https://kristinita.ru/Sublime-Text/Sacagawea) на моём сайте. Gemini Scrollbar поддерживает: большие возможности по кастомизации скролллбара, мобильные устройства, медиа-запросы, переходы по якорям на странице, изменение размеров окна, lazy loading, поиск по странице посредством `Ctrl+F`. У альтернатив Gemini Scrollbar я находил баги по данным параметрам. [**Имеющиеся баги Gemini Scrollbar**](https://github.com/noeldelgado/gemini-scrollbar/issues) для меня не критичны.

Comment: Также Gemini Scrollbar позволяет просто скрыть нативные скроллбары браузеров, [**пример**](https://kristinita.ru/404). Спасибо.